# Move submenu in Wordpress Admin

Tags: wordpress, submenu

I just created a custom menu in my Wordpress admin with `add_menu_page`, how can I move an already existing submenu (e.g. Appearance > Header) under this new top-level menu?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found you can call the global $submenu. With this variable you can move the submenu's allready present like so:

```
global $submenu

foreach ($submenu['index.php'] as $key => $subItem) {
    if ($subItem[2] === 'update-core.php') {
        $submenu['options-general.php'][0.1] = $subItem;

        ksort($submenu['options-general.php']);
    }
}
unset($submenu['index.php'][$key];
```

The one thing I have not yet figured out though is how to make the wp admin recognize the change of parent (aka the submenu has not expanded when I am on this submenu page).

Hope to find some improvements for this answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
For adding submenu to main menu.Follow the below steps:


1. Go to Appearance->Menus.In Menus window,on right hand side,you will see the added 
   menus list.Just move the mouse over the menu name which you want to be the sub menu,an 
   hand symbol will come,then just drag and move the menu little bit to the right side 
   below the main menu to which you want this menu to be the sub menu.
```

Comment: I don't think you've read the question. He's asking how to edit the wp-admin menu. Not a menu on the front-end